# Laravel, Composer update. No such file app/Helpers/Functions/core.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy Laravel in my local machine, using `composer update` and I got error:

> PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/project/public/vendor/composer/../../app/Helpers/Functions/core.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/project/public/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

I tried to delete `composer.lock` and update again. Same issue. `app/Helpers/Functions/core.php` there really no files, but I didn't find any suggestions how to get that files.

Comment: Please try from your project root `composer install`. It may cause, the required packages are not installed.

Comment: You may try:  composer update --no-scripts

Comment: "Please try from your project root composer install. It may cause, the required packages are not installed" - I did it, and that's didn't help. Same issue

Comment: The composer autoloader seems to have outdated data. Try deleting the `vendor` folder completely and run `composer install` again.

Answer (score 0):

There was not existing some files, app/ filder